# How can I force a webview app to open links in it instead of open them in the default android browser depending on the domain?

Tags: android, webview

I've just begun developing android apps, so I need some help with my webview app which is easy to understand. So, this is my specific question:

How can I force a webview app to open links in it instead of open them in the default browser depending on domain?

Please enclose an edited/expanded version of this code with your answer:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("www.example.com");
```

The domain whose content I want to open in webview is, let's say: www.qwerty.com Every other link should be open by the default browser.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to create a `WebViewClient`:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then set it to your `WebView` like this:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Comment: WOW!!! Thank you for the very fast answer! But: Where do I have to input the domain, in my case www.qwerty.com?

Comment: You don't need to put in a domain. The WebViewClient will override every domain.

Comment: But now every link opens in webview. That's not what I wanted. Only links with the domain name "www.querty.com" should open in webview... Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

You have to evaluate the url passed in the custom `WebViewClient`. 
The *boolean* `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` has a true and a false value. 
When **true**, you send the url to the browser, when **false**, you stay in the `WebView`.

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.qwerty.com")) {
        /* 
         This is my web site, so do not override; 
         let my WebView load the page
        */
        return false;
    }
       /* 
         Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, 
         so launch another Activity that handles URLs
       */
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;    
    }
}
```

Then from your Activity you call indeed the new `WebClient`

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```