# Webapp View Opening links in Browser

Tags: android, webview

I am very new to coding and followed a guide on creating a webview app.
It displays the homepage perfectly fine until you click on anything and it open the browser but should remain in the webview app.

I tried to follow some of the other posts ([How can I force a webview app to open links in it instead of open them in the default android browser depending on the domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633367/how-can-i-force-a-webview-app-to-open-links-in-it-instead-of-open-them-in-the-de)) but Webviewclient, webview, uri , intent and Startactity cannot solve symbols. So I figured since the tutorial code looks different it had something else in the code limiting me or there is a few things I need to create? Here is my activity code (I removed the URL name):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

            WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("https://www..com");

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force a webview app to open links in it instead of open them in the default android browser depending on the domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633367/how-can-i-force-a-webview-app-to-open-links-in-it-instead-of-open-them-in-the-de)

Comment: I tried that but didn't work.
If I create the WebViewClient class with below:

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

Where in the Activity code must this go?
webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:") || url.startsWith("smsto:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") || url.startsWith("mms:") || url.startsWith("mmsto:") || url.startsWith("market:") || url.startsWith("https://youtu.be/")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

If your link start with by example `:mailto` it will open the gmail app. If you don't add that it will not open the email-adress. In that if I have also added    `url.startsWith("https://youtu.be/")` if some link links to youtube it will open the Youtube instead of loading it in the webview

Answer (score -1):

```
mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        // do your handling codes here, which url is the requested url 
        // probably you need to open that url rather than redirect: 
        view.loadUrl(url); 
        return false; // then it is not handled by default action 
    } 
});
```

Comment: return false from the overided method